# How to ensure a small UnitOfWork job is completed on a windows service Stop or Shutdown

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, windows-services, task-parallel-library

I have a job that run every X seconds that shouldn't take long to execute (less than 5 seconds) that is ran in a WindowsService. My goal is to ensure that a currently running job will complete it's execution if the Windows Service is stopped in the middle of it's execution.

This thread seemed interesting, but it doesn't work so far:
[Task Handling on Application Shutdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12120349/task-handling-on-application-shutdown)

Any help will be appreciated.

**WindowsService implementation:**

```
public partial class WindowsService : ServiceBase
{
    private readonly ILogger logger;
    private readonly IStartJob startJob;
    private readonly CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource;
    private Task task;

    public WindowsService(IStartJob startJob, ILogger logger)
    {
        // Dependancy injection of logger and JobStarter
        this.startJob = startJob;
        this.logger = logger;
        InitializeComponent();
        cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        task = new Task(() => startJob.Start(cancellationTokenSource.Token), 
            cancellationTokenSource.Token, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
        task.Start();
        logger.Info("Service started");
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        RequestAdditionalTime(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30).Milliseconds);
        cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
        try { task.Wait(); }
        catch (Exception ex) { logger.Error("Error while stopping the Service", ex); }
        logger.Info("Service stopped");
    }
}
```

**StartJob Implementation:**

```
public class StartJob : IStartJob
{
    private readonly ILogger logger;
    private readonly IExecuteJob executeJob;
    private DateTime lastExecution = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-1);

    public StartJob(ILogger logger, IExecuteJob executeJob)
    {
        this.logger = logger;
        this.executeJob = executeJob;
    }

    public async void Start(CancellationToken token)
    {
        while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            var nextExecution = lastExecution.AddSeconds(5);
            if (nextExecution < DateTime.UtcNow)
            {
                try
                {
                    logger.Info("Start Job Execution");
// To similate long process not ended, break point here
// and stop the service before continuing the execution.
                    Thread.Sleep(5000);
                    executeJob.Execute();   
                    logger.Info("Job completed");
                    AdjustLastExecution(nextExecution);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    logger.Error("Unexpected exception while executing job", ex);
                }
            }
// Would expect the cancelToken to activate here or in the while condition
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), token);
        }
    }

    private void AdjustLastExecution(DateTime nextExecution)
    {
        // To ensure we have an heartbeat close to 5 seconds
        lastExecution = nextExecution.AddSeconds(5) > DateTime.UtcNow  ?
            nextExecution : DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds(-5);
    }
}
```

I tried a bunch of variations with the cancelToken present in the entry task, task wait and wait millisecondsTimeout, but nothing did the trick so far.

I attached my solution to the executing WindowsService and ensure that the executing job would be in the middle of it with break points and Thread.Sleep. But the Job completed log isn't written and the attached processed is dropped before it.

Comment: Why to mark your `Start` method async? You are already starting it inside the Task, you do not need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I shortly looked at your code and only thing I would try is

to replace :

```
async void
```

with

```
async Task
```

I don't guarantee that it applies to your case, but I recalled reading this article recommending to avoid *async void*.

> In C#, async void methods are a scourge upon your code..

[Haacked.com | Avoid async void methods](http://haacked.com/archive/2014/11/11/async-void-methods/)

EDIT :

```
task = new Task(() => startJob.Start(cancellationTokenSource.Token), 
        cancellationTokenSource.Token, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
```

with

```
task = startJob.Start(cancellationTokenSource.Token);
```

Comment: I try and it didn't solved the issue, although it won't hurt, thanks for the input.
Will read the Microsoft best practices to find if it ring any bells.

Comment: Forgot to add : Did you update OnStart method? You don't need "new Task()" anymore.

Comment: That did the trick, the async void method or async Task method inside a new Task don't let the RequestAdditionalTime() to work properly. I did some permutations and tests and you also need to ensure you don't put the cancellationToken in the task.Wait(), otherwise it won't complete the jobExecution.

Do you know if not specifying TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning will cause any issue?

I ask because that Windows service will run until the next deployment (probably for weeks non stop).

Comment: That's greate! Regarding LongRunning you must research whether it applies to async, and yes, current fix has actually changed what you originally intended with it. Did you try @VMAtm suggestions to make Start() just standard non-async method?